# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Parenting breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  3         12
Users destroyed                                  31          0
Users deleted                                     8          0
Users contacted                                   4          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           213        652
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               22        147
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         12        104
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               28        195
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                68        820
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               58        428
Tags merged                                       2          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             2          2
Tag synonyms created                              4          0
Revisions redacted                                3          0
Questions unprotected                             1          0
Questions reopened                               27          2
Questions protected                              14         45
Questions migrated                                8          1
Questions flagged⁴                                6        257
Questions closed                                283         32
Question flags handled⁴                         179         84
Posts unlocked                                    0          6
Posts undeleted                                  16          8
Posts locked                                      5         72
Posts deleted⁵                                  782        464
Posts bumped                                      0         36
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments undeleted                               58          0
Comments flagged                                  2        374
Comments deleted⁶                             2,024        469
Comment flags handled                           266        110
Answers flagged                                  27      1,252
Answer flags handled                          1,081        198
All comments on a post moved to chat             54          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...